# SQL Server 2016 through SSMS: Fixed week end date and month end date Snapshot Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering if there is a way when a **Weekly** report is pulled whether it is done on Saturday or Sunday that my snapshot date would be always displaying Saturday's date. This will allow me not to go and change my week end date(Saturday)in case we need to manually run the report the next day(Sunday).

Same thing for **monthly** reports, I need the month end date to be fixed in case the report run correctly the last date of the current month or the day after (1st of next month).

Thx everyone.

Comment: I am on SQL Server 2016 through SSMS

Comment: Please add a little more input to your question: what do you expect if the report is executed on wednesday, thursday or any other day? Do you always expect the report to display the values for the previous saturday? Same for the monthly report: ehat do you expect if it is executed on any other day od the month except the first and the last day of the month?

Answer (score 0):

To get the previous Saturday date or previous month end - see these examples:

```
Select dt.inputDate
     , PreviousSaturday = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 5, dt.inputDate) / 7 * 7, 5)
     , PreviousMonthEnd = dateadd(month, datediff(month, -1, dt.inputDate) - 1, -1)
   From (Values (12), (11), (10), (9), (8), (7), (6), (5), (4), (3), (2), (1), (0)) As t(n)
  Cross Apply (Values (dateadd(day, -t.n, getdate()))) As dt(inputDate)
```

Comment: Hi, I ended up using a slightly different approach. 

-For the Week End Date is used it with the Day Name: 

CASE WHEN DATENAME(W, GETDATE())='Saturday' THEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) ELSE CAST(DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())-0),DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS DATE) END AS 'Week_End_Date'. 

-For the Month End Date as well: 

CASE WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CAST(dateadd(month, datediff(month, -1, getdate()) - 1, -1) AS DATE) ELSE CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) END  AS 'Month_End_Date' –

Answer (score 0):

If you use the U.S. region and SQL Server 2016:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY
              ,CASE DATEPART(Weekday, GETDATE()) 
                     --1 = Sun 2 = Mon 3 = Tues 4= Wed 5 = Thu 6 = Fri 7 = Sat
                     WHEN 1 THEN -1
                     WHEN 2 THEN -2
                     WHEN 3 THEN -3
                     WHEN 4 THEN -4
                     WHEN 5 THEN -5
                     WHEN 6 THEN -6
                     WHEN 7 THEN 0
               END
              ,CAST(GETDATE() as date)
       ) AS [Previous_Saturday]

      ,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1
       ) AS [Previous_Month_End]
```

Produces output:

```
Previous_Saturday Previous_Month_End
----------------- ------------------
2021-05-08        2021-05-01
```

DATEFROMPARTS is available in SQL Server 2016 and up. Weekday values may change for different regions.